# Redirecting .html URL in Svelte

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm migrating a site to sveltekit. The older site had a `/foo.html` URL and svelte seems to work best with `/foo`.

What is the most idiomatic way in svelte to set up a 301 redirect from `/foo.html` to `/foo` for existing links and such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SvelteKit does not use trailing slashes by default (i.e. the path would be `/foo`), the most common case where you would employ it, is static site generation for deployment servers that only serve `index.html` files, so you would get a `foo/index.html`.

The [route](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing) file would always be the same: `src/routes/foo/+page.svelte`

How exactly that is served is dependent on the configuration (such as [`trailingSlash`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#trailingslash) and [`prerender`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#prerender)) and [adapter being used](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters). So if you you use the static adapter, do *not* enable trailing slash and have the route pre-render, you should end up with a `foo.html` anyway, so you would not need a redirect.

If you do need to set up redirects, that can be done in [hooks](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#server-hooks), that way you do not need additional route files.

Comment: Ah, good point. I meant `/foo`. Edited.